# Add Linq statement to a Web API Get with a filter, i'm trying to add $select

Tags: linq, asp.net-web-api, odata

I trying to apply some linq statements to all my Get Web api commands.  I figured I could do this using an `ActionFilterAttribute`.

I'm basically adding $select support in web api since its currently not supported.  I'm not sure where to get the `IQueryable` results.  I believe I need it before sql execution happens but after Get function has returned the `IQueryable` result. Any help would be great.  I'm trying something similiar to [this post](http://forums.asp.net/t/1785490.aspx/3/10), but his idea will not work because `HttpResponseMessage response = actionExecutedContext.Result;` is no longer in RC.

Thanks
Nick

---

### solution

```
        public override void OnActionExecuted(System.Web.Http.Filters.HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
        HttpRequestMessage request = actionExecutedContext.Request;
        HttpResponseMessage response = actionExecutedContext.Response;

        IQueryable obj;

        if (response != null && response.TryGetContentValue(out obj) && request.RequestUri.ParseQueryString()["$select"] != null)
        {

            System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection QueryItems = request.RequestUri.ParseQueryString();
            string select = QueryItems["$select"];

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(select))
            {
                obj = obj.Select(string.Format("new ({0})", select));

            }

            //
            //this should be generic not hard coded for Json
            //
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);

            actionExecutedContext.Response = actionExecutedContext.Request.CreateResponse();
            actionExecutedContext.Response.Content = new StringContent(json);
            actionExecutedContext.Response.Content.Headers.Clear();
            actionExecutedContext.Response.Content.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
            actionExecutedContext.Response.StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK;

        }


    }
```

Comment: I've built a solution and I will post it tomorrow after I have cleaned up the code.

Answer (score 0):

see the original post above. I added the solution to the bottom.